# Why can't I declare a static constexpr variable in a template class using msvc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gnu, constexpr

I have a template class, and I want to declare a static constexpr variable of the same type of the class. With gnu compiler it works just fine, but with
Microsoft Visual Studio, it won't compile. Am I doing something wrong and it is jest the gnu compiler that is very kind with me, or is it the Microsoft compiler that is at fault?
I know I can fix it changing the variable for a function that does the same thing, but I'm curious.

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T One() noexcept { return static_cast<T>( 1 ); }

template <typename T>
struct Test {
    T val;

    static constexpr Test example{ One<T>() };                    // compiles only with gnu
    static constexpr Test Example() { return Test{ One<T>() }; }  // compiles with both gnu and microsoft
};
```

The given error (Visal Studio 2017) is :

> error C2017 : use of undefined type 'Test'

Comment: Which exact version of MSVC?

Comment: I was trying it before also on compiler explorer, and even with version 19.20 it doesn't compile

Comment: Because GNU is too much tolerant!! `example` should have a return statment!

Comment: But it is a varable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the last `}` your `Test` template type is incomplete.

Here’s [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22770318/126995) which adds third compiler. As you see, the answer says VC++ and clang respect the standard, gcc doesn’t.

Comment: yea, doing some tests, if the class isn't template gnu also prevents from declaring incomplete types, so I guess the fact it compiled must have been some template shenenigan.